# Random Bluescreen of Death

Tags: bsod, visual-studio-code

can someone help me why am I getting this random blue screen? It say's whea uncorrectable error but I don't know which part of my PC is faulty. I noticed the BSOD appears when there is a heavy task like when I am coding in VSCode (running npm install, etc). I will attach here the minidump incase someone can read it. If you need more information about my PC, let me know. Please I really need your help. I want to use this PC for programming. Thanks!

[Laters Minidump File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qyqGmTH8gCqncn0C6VVNXc4PjtGA_Lxj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: For the computer you have run the Manufacturer's driver update App, and update BIOS, Video and Chipset (if one).  Use Nirsoft Blue Screen View to look at the Mini Dump file.

Comment: I've updated all drivers and BIOS already but the BSOD still appears. My SSD is new so I don't think it's the one that causes the problem. I also ran tests (memtest86 and windows memory diagnostic) and got no errors. I also tried to use bluescreenview and the highlighted ones are **ntoskrnl.exe** and **PSHED.dll** but I have no idea what these are. Sorry

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x124---whea-uncorrectable-error    Look up Bugcheck 0x124 and it points to a fatal hardware error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error arrives inside `PSHED.dll`, defined as
"Platform Specific Hardware Error Driver".
Conclusion: You have a serious hardware problem.

Actions that may help:

- Check the Event Viewer for error messages that might pinpoint the malfunctioning
  device
- Update Windows to the latest version
- Update all device drivers (consult the manufacturers' websites for recent drivers)
- Run `Windows memory diagnostic` from the Start menu
- Run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) overnight
- Run `chkdsk` on all disk drives and check for errors
- Run CMD as Administrator and enter the following commands:

  - [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
  - [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- Disable overclocking (if you did any)
- Lastly, take the computer to be checked in a repair-shop.